# Checking data behind pointer at runtime to avoid segfaults : (wchar_t *) vs. (char *)

Tags: c, string-formatting, variadic-functions, typechecking

I have a `printf`-like function that can handle `%s` (`char *`) and `%ls` (`wchar_t *`) conversions. Everything works fine if I pass the right argument for the right conv specifier.

But if I pass a `char *` to my function when it expects a `wchar_t *`, it may segfault (Null-terminating byte being located at the second byte of a `wchar_t` for instance). Since I access this argument through `va_arg()` I can't be sure of the type.

If I consider that this `char` array is always NUL-terminated, I could check byte after byte to correctly handle the NUL-terminating char and stop memory access after it. But then I wouldn't be able to handle `wchar_t` legit values like this :

```
0b XXXXXXXX XXXXXXXX 00000000 XXXXXXXX
```

I'm already using the `__attribute__` printf GNU C extension. But I this function may be used by a python programm through [`ctypes`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/ctypes.html), so format/type checking at compiling may not be enough.

It there a way to perform such checking at runtime in my C function?

(*NB* : "There is no such way" may be the answer, but I'm still asking in order to be completely sure.)

Comment: If it is going to be used through python, have you considered writing a wrapper for it in python?

Comment: at runtime you can't but at compile time it's could be possible to write a compiler extension that verify your parameters. But this is not an issue in C, you could just let the user crash.

Comment: Also I don't believe this is possible in C (you would actually need to pass runtime type information, which C does not support).

Comment: "Checking pointer type at runtime" - What use does this have? C is statically typed!

Comment: @Olaf Maybe "checking data type/structure at a memory address" would be more accurate then.

Comment: @vmonteco: That does not change anything! It still is statically typed. Using a differen type invokes undefined behaviour. If you try something "hackish", you are on your own. Don't try to outsmart your compiler; modern compilers are quite unforgiving.

Comment: @BenSteffan I'm actually considering solving this part of my problem python-side and that's what I plan to do if I can't do it C-side, indeed!

Comment: Type-checking in Python is frowned upon. Y>ou might use exceptions, but otherwise use duck-typing. And in general: **write correct code**!

Comment: That's an XY problem. Once you have the wrong type, you wrote wrong code. That's what testing and debugging are for. Also enabling all recommended compiler warnings and fixing them is **strongly** advised.

Comment: if you cannot solve your problem any other way, you could try validating the encoding: at least in case of  UTF32 (ie 4-byte `wchar_t`), you'll be able to catch quite a bit of incorrect usage as the highest unicode codepoint is `0x10FFFF`

Comment: @Christoph I've considered this, but wchar_t values could contain nul octets too (if that's what you were thinking about).

Comment: @Olaf Then on C-side I should just fall back to considering my function will be used the right way and I shouldn't care about handling such case?

Comment: @vmonteco: the check works the other way around: if you have a `char` based string that's longer than 3 characters, you're likely to get an invalid codepoint as the highest 11 bits won't be zero

Comment: @Olaf Anyway, if I consider that the pointer was pointing to a wrong-type data, I could as well consider that the array isn't NUL-terminated, that the address contained in the pointer is wrong and that trying to access it would trigger a segfault too in a way.

Comment: @vmonteco: That's the idea of the C language! It is weakly typed, and you must not invoke undefined behaviour. A good **modern** (i.e. C99 - better C11) C book will help, read it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not possible.

In a typical C implementation, the type system only exists as an aid at compile time.*  At runtime, all you have is bytes of data, and there's no way to even tell a pointer from a number (besides educated guessing).

Technically, you're not even allowed to `va_arg(ap, const char*)` and then examine memory if the original argument was not a `char*`, `signed char*`, `unsigned char*` or `void*`, or a `const`-related version of such a type.  The type passed to `va_arg` is always required to be a compatible type.  (One reason is there's no guarantee pointers to different types have the same size, layout, and meaning.)

(*In C++ there's a bit more to the story, because data representing types is stored connected to polymorphic objects to make `dynamic_cast` and `typeid` work correctly, and associated with all exception objects to make `catch` blocks work correctly.  But none of this is compatible with `va_arg`.)